# RstudioからのGithub操作

Tags: git, r, github

Github初心者です。
RStudioからGithubを操作しようと試みていますが、デスクトップ上のすべてのファイルが必要ないファイルまでGitの管理状態になってしまい困っています。
チェックボックスにチェックが入っていますが押しても外れない状況です。
Ignoreしようとしていますが固まって動きません。
わかる方よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudioのGitパネルでは、Git管理下にないフォルダが含まれる場合、
そのフォルダにチェックを入れた時にフォルダ内に含まれる全てのファイルを選択します。

対象のファイルが多い場合、RStudioのGitパネルでそれを処理するのは時間がかかると思いますので、Gitパネルからの操作ではなく、直接 `.gitignore` を編集するのが良いと思います。`.gitignore` にGit管理から外したいファイル・フォルダ名を記述することで、管理の対象外になるためGitパネルにも表示されなくなります。

あるいはRStudioのGitパネルから、対象のファイル・フォルダを選択した状態（チェックは入れない。ファイル名などを直接クリクすると青色の選択状態になる）で右クリック、Ignore… を選ぶと `.gitignore` にそのファイルが追加することができます。この時、Shiftキーと一緒に別のファイルを選択すると複数ファイルの選択が有効になります。

Comment: RStudioのGit ignoreのウインドウを開いてDirectoryをC:/Users/hoge/Desktopにして.gitignoreに*.jpgなどをまとめて登録し、更新ボタンを押しましたが？マークにならずAマークのままです。また、GitパネルをみるとDesktop/hogehogeというのと"Desktop/hogehoge"というものがあるのですがこれにはどういう違いがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: `.gitignore`に関して詳細・例は[ここ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: 結局プロジェクトを作り直したらあっさり行きました。
ご解答非常に分かりやすかったです。ありがとうございました。